# How to remove large files in GitHub?

Tags: github, limit

I had some large files in my GitHub path. When I tried:

```
git add *
git commit
git push
```

It gave me this error:

> this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

I removed these files and tried again, but the error still appears. How can I successfully push files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), which allows a total size of 1 GB per user. Then you can still push those files!

If you have the large files in your commit history, you'll have to rewrite that, as you'd still be pushing files larger than 100 MB (just on an old commit).